# Card block with a transform scale CSS property loses its border-radius when hovered

Tags: css, css-transforms

When hovering [those product cards](https://product-list-two.vercel.app/) that have a `transform: scale(1.03)` the `border-radius` disappears. Is there a way of making the card scale on hover without that effect?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your `border-radius` is disappearing because the element with the radius is scaling within a parent element that has fixed sizing, cause the overflow scaling to be obscured. A way to maintain the `border-radius` consistent is to apply it to the parent element while applying the hover `transform` to the contents so that the radius does not scale.

```css
.slide {
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 30px;
    width: 150px;
}
.slide div {
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}
.slide:hover div {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="slide">
  <div class="contents">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <h2>Subtitle</h2>
    <p>Description</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slide">
  <div class="contents">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <h2>Subtitle</h2>
    <p>Description</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering back, that makes total sense and I'll keep it in mind for the next time. Unfortunately, that did not solve the problem this time. When I apply the transform to the parent div `.slick-slide.slick-active > div:hover` it keeps "hiding" the border-radius.